# Using display: block with bottom-border on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to do my hover like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhk1s.png .

I have done something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/szsq2424/

If I use that hover using `botom-border` without `display: block` on anchor elements, ir looks like i want. But when I use `display: block` on `a` elements in white header class (to make all the button clickable, not just the text) , it takes that border down to the bottom of the button. Some ideas friends ?? Thanks ! I am new to html + css , appreciate the help !

Comment: Can you change your markup?

Comment: Remove `line-height` from `<li>` and give padding to `li` to achieve space arround `<a>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text inside the anchor with a span and apply the border to that.

```css
.white-header {
  width: 1400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.white-header ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.white-header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.white-header ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.white-header ul li a:link,
.white-header ul li a:visited {
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.white-header ul li a:hover {
  color: #57C5A0;
}

.white-header ul li a:hover span {
  color: #57C5A0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #57C5A0;
}

/********
FIRST BUTTON
********/

.white-first {
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #383838;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
}

/********
SECOND BUTTON
*********/

.white-second {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
  margin: 0;
}

.white-second a:link,
.white-second a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.white-second a:hover {
  color: #57C5A0;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
}

/******
VISA LIETUVA BUTTON
*******/

.white-third {
  width: 270px;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
}
```

```html
  <header class="white-header">
        <ul>
            <li class="white-first"><a href="#"><span>Pramogos</span></a></li>
          <li class="white-second"><a href="#"><span>Pramogos</span></a></li>
          <li class="white-third"><a href="#"><span>Pramogos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
 </header>
```

Comment: How I didn't think about it myself... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

you can add `text-decoration: underline` to `:hover` to achieve result like on provided image

Comment: You can't change the color of `text-decoration: underline`.

Comment: on provided image there is same color on underline and on text.